# Mongo DB $near query in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
var query ="{'Geo':{'$near': {'$geometry': {'type': 'Point' ,'coordinates':[]} }}}";
var parsing = BsonDocument.Parse(query);
var qwithcoor = parsing["Geo"]["$near"]["$geometry"]["coordinates"].AsBsonArray;
qwithcoor.AddRange(coordinates);
parsing["Geo"]["$near"].AsBsonDocument.Add("$maxDistance", radius);

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");
var documents = await collection.Find(parsing).ToListAsync();
```

I want to do this with `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter`. Like this:

```
var query=Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Near();
var documents=await collection.Find(query).ToListAsync();
```

do I use Near after the Filter? What are the Near parameters?

Answer (score 3):

I solve this with

```
var gp =new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]));
var query=Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Near("Geo",gp,radius);
var result = await col.Find(query).ToListAsync();
```